# Phrase for "Sharing the same feelings for each other"

Tags: idioms

Can anybody help me with a good idiom or phrase which means "Sharing the same feelings for each other?

Comment: The feeling is mutual

Comment: Slight comment on @NVZ's answer - people would more commonly (I believe) say "The feeling's mutual", ie the contracted version.  Also it's worth pointing out that this would generally be said by **one of the people concerned**, rather than some third party.

Comment: Reciprocate....

Comment: Can you write an example sentence where the idiom or phrase would be used? The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: The feelings are mutual, requited, reciprocated, shared, returned ...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUfLHJg-CY0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feelings are **mutual** ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mutual))

> 1. possessed, experienced, performed, etc., by each of two or more with respect to the other; reciprocal:
>    to have mutual respect.
> 2. having the same relation each toward the other:
>    to be mutual enemies.
> 3. of or relating to each of two or more; held in common; shared:
>    mutual interests.

The feelings are **requited** ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/requited))

> verb (used with object), requited, requiting.
>
> 5. to give or do in return.

Comment: +1 Because "requited" is good. But you should always read the comments on a question before answering. "mutual feelings" was answered by @NVZ. I'd have not voted up if it weren't for "requite." anyways, nice answer.

Comment: That comment unfortunately showed up as I was composing my answer, and I neglected to refresh before posting. That said, I'm not sure why it was posted as a comment instead of an answer in its own right, but I'm relatively new to this community and the way "things are done".

Comment: No worries. It is a suggestion to see what others have commented. It is not against the rules though.

Comment: It's fine, I gave the first up vote for this answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Mutual feelings** is the correct answer, as provide earlier.

I'm suggesting this because it will be helpful in several situations.

Having a sense of **fellow feeling** means the feeling you get due to shared feelings or experiences. If there is a sense of **fellow feeling** between two or among few people, it is because they have a hell of a lot of *mutual feelings*.

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fellow%20feeling)

> A feeling of shared interest or understanding

Answer (score 0):

The feelings are reciprocated.

This would imply that the feelings are mutual, closely matched and known to both parties.

Comment: Is " I dont think you reciprocate my feelings for you" a valid sentence ?

Comment: I would say "I don't think my feelings for you are reciprocated"

Comment: WHY is what i wrote wrong?